# How to get the lines that were executed in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, cyclomatic-complexity

I would like to get the lines that were executed in a really big execution path. I'm using Pharo 4.0

Is there a way to instrument this in an image without having to manually tag relevant methods? or maybe there is an alternative that will help to achieve similar result?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you need to measure coverage, or this about the entire execution path?

Comment: I don't want coverage, just want to measure just one execution path. I don't know what you mean with entire because my system has different starting points.

Comment: What do you want to measure in that execution path?

Comment: Hoy many lines were executed

Comment: Lines seem hard to relate to execution, because they exist only in the source code. It seems easier to count executed bytecodes and I think that you could intervene the interpreter to do that

Comment: You can count the message sends / method invocations, but not the lines involved. I wonder why would you need to do that.